# adicionando dados coluna Data Frame

Tags: python, dataframe

Esse é algoritmo que analisa a taxa de retorno de alguns investimentos de acordo com sua rentabilidade.
Estou travado no seguinte código Python3:

```
tx = (df['Ult'] / df['Pfechamento']) * 100
df['TaxaRetorno'] = tx.round(2)
for i,analise in enumerate(df['TaxaRetorno']):
    if analise > 1:
        analise = 'Montar'

df['Analise'] = analise
```

O retorno o Data Frame está retornando tudo como 'Montar' e o que preciso é que quando a condição seja verdadeira a coluna análise tenha 'Montar' ou se for falso fique em branco ou a palavra 'Aguardar'.

Abaixo tem o output. O que preciso é que nas linhas {2,3,4} na coluna "Analise" fique em branco ou nome "Aguardar".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vejo alguns problemas no código:

- a variável `analise` esta sendo utilizada fora do `for`, então você esta usando o ultimo valor colocado nela;
- `df['Analise'] = analise` esse trecho esta criando uma nova coluna e aplicando o mesmo valor para todos os registros, que aparentemente não é o que você deseja fazer;
- o fato de você esta usando pandas esse `for` torna-se desnecessário;

#### Corrigindo o código e mantendo o `for`

<sup>**Obs.:** Estou fazendo isso só para você ver como setar um valor em um índice especifico usando pandas, já que você esta usando pandas não há necessidade desse `for`</sup>

```
dados = {
    'Ult':[0.26,0.28,0.19],
    'Pfechamento':[25.85, 26.00, 26.85],
}

df = pd.DataFrame( dados )

tx = (df['Ult'] / df['Pfechamento']) * 100
df['TaxaRetorno'] = tx.round(2)
df['Analise'] = ''
for i,analise in enumerate(df['TaxaRetorno']):
    if analise > 1:
        df.loc[ i , 'Analise'] = 'Montar'
        # usei o .loc para acessar o `index` e a `coluna` e setar um valor
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/Y14I7J)</sup>

#### Usando o pandas ao invés de fazer o `for`

```
dados = {
    'Ult':[0.26,0.28,0.19],
    'Pfechamento':[25.85, 26.00, 26.85],
}

df = pd.DataFrame( dados )

tx = (df['Ult'] / df['Pfechamento']) * 100
df['TaxaRetorno'] = tx.round(2)
df['Analise'] = ''

tabela_verdade = (df['TaxaRetorno'] > 1)
# criar uma tabela verdade, onde você terá `true` 
# os casos em que a condição  `TaxaRetorno > 1` for verdade, 
# então usando os 3 primeiros itens da sua df como exemplo você 
# terá um `pandas.Series` parecida com (veja o exemplo online): 
#  
#  0     True
#  1     True
#  2    False

df.loc[ tabela_verdade , 'Analise'] = 'Montar'
# utilizar o `.loc` passando a `tabela verdade` e o `nome da coluna`
# associando um valor a ela só vai aplicar nos registros em que a `tabela verdade`
# indicar `true` para o index, então nesse exemplo ele vai aplicar nos index `0` e `1`
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/3gAVvw)</sup>

> #### Referencia
>
> [pandas.DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc)